# Heroku ImportError - Gunicorn still trying to run deleted instead of new app?

Tags: django, heroku, importerror

Yesterday I worked through the Heroku Dev Center tutorial for getting started with Django on Heroku. Using that tutorial, I created an app called "oldtestapp"...

Today I went to heroku.com, logged in, and deleted oldtestapp. I have an existing Django project that I wish to migrate to Heroku. I copied over the Procfile and requirements.txt from the oldtestapp to my new app's root directory (the same dir that manage.py is in). I changed the Procfile: where it said "oldtestapp.wsgi" I changed it to "newapp.wsgi" where newapp is the name of my Django application. I opened git bash in the root directory for that project (the same dir that manage.py is in) and successfully pushed everything to git and heroku.

I got an Internal Server Error when I did `heroku open`. The logs are below (I replaced my email with emailaddress@email.com):

```
$ heroku logs
2013-07-17T23:09:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-07-17T23:09:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: no Ced
ar-supported app detected
2013-07-17T23:15:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
←[36m2013-07-17T23:17:07.691491+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[36m2013-07-17T23:17:07.728257+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy e6cec10 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[36m2013-07-17T23:17:07.775009+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v3 created by emailaddress@email.com
←[36m2013-07-17T23:17:07.812132+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy e6cec10 by emailadd
ress@email.com
2013-07-17T23:17:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:15.119247+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `gunicorn oldtestapp.wsgi`
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.533626+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [2] [I
NFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:43432 (2)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.535035+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [2] [I
NFO] Using worker: sync
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.531496+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [2] [I
NFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.567349+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [7] [I
NFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     worker.init_process()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.wsgi = self.app.w
sgi()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [7] [E
RROR] Exception in worker process:
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent cal
l last):
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_proce
ss
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module nam
ed oldtestapp.wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     __import__(module)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent cal
l last):
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return util.import_app
(self.app_uri)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_proce
ss
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.callable = self.l
oad()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return util.import_app
(self.app_uri)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     worker.init_process()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.callable = self.l
oad()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.620526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:17 [7] [I
NFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     __import__(module)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module nam
ed oldtestapp.wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.618410+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.wsgi = self.app.w
sgi()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:17.699855+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:18.100018+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:18 [2] [I
NFO] Shutting down: Master
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:18.104067+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:18 [2] [I
NFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:19.804175+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 3
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:24.727149+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `gunicorn oldtestapp.wsgi`
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.684787+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [2] [I
NFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.685477+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [2] [I
NFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10242 (2)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.689543+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [2] [I
NFO] Using worker: sync
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.698842+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [7] [I
NFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [7] [E
RROR] Exception in worker process:
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     worker.init_process()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     __import__(module)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.callable = self.l
oad()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_proce
ss
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in spawn_worker
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return util.import_app
(self.app_uri)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent cal
l last):
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.wsgi = self.app.w
sgi()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.callable = self.l
oad()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Traceback (most recent cal
l last):
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_proce
ss
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 115, in wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.716897+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return util.import_app
(self.app_uri)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     worker.init_process()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     __import__(module)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 353, in import_app
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.wsgi = self.app.w
sgi()
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717176+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module nam
ed oldtestapp.wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ImportError: No module nam
ed oldtestapp.wsgi
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/pytho
n/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 33, in load
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.717331+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [7] [I
NFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.863220+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [2] [I
NFO] Shutting down: Master
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:25.863355+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:17:25 [2] [I
NFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:27.176443+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
tus 3
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:27.194233+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to crashed
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:19.814946+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up t
o crashed
←[33m2013-07-17T23:17:19.815657+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from cras
hed to starting
2013-07-17T23:19:20+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
←[36m2013-07-17T23:20:01.083451+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 339f362 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[36m2013-07-17T23:20:01.121450+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v4 created by che
riexress@email.com
←[36m2013-07-17T23:20:01.164786+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 339f362 by emailadd
ress@email.com
2013-07-17T23:20:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
←[33m2013-07-17T23:20:08.957935+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
←[33m2013-07-17T23:20:01.520877+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from cras
hed to starting
←[36m2013-07-17T23:23:26.902944+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[32m2013-07-17T23:23:32.825464+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/favicon.ico host=secret-falls-6154.herokuapp.com fwd="69.249.253.220" dyno=we
b.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=135
←[32m2013-07-17T23:27:34.455499+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/ host=pathetic.herokuapp.com fwd="69.249.253.220" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms serv
ice=11ms status=500 bytes=135
←[32m2013-07-17T23:27:34.782763+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/favicon.ico host=pathetic.herokuapp.com fwd="69.249.253.220" dyno=web.1 conne
ct=2ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=135
←[32m2013-07-17T23:27:34.959360+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/favicon.ico host=pathetic.herokuapp.com fwd="69.249.253.220" dyno=web.1 conne
ct=2ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=135
←[36m2013-07-17T23:27:46.177839+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=0 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[33m2013-07-17T23:27:46.404001+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from up t
o down
←[36m2013-07-17T23:44:26.986606+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by emailadd
ress@email.com
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:34.147645+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
ommand `gunicorn pathetic.wsgi`
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:45.317811+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:44:45 [2] [I
NFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:45.318913+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:44:45 [2] [I
NFO] Using worker: sync
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:45.318772+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:44:45 [2] [I
NFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:9194 (2)
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:45.334904+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m 2013-07-17 23:44:45 [7] [I
NFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
←[33m2013-07-17T23:44:45.397342+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
ting to up
```

It looks to me like there is an error with `Starting process with command 'gunicorn oldtestapp.wsgi'` and `ImportError: No module named oldtestapp.wsgi` ...it seems like Heroku is still trying to tell gunicorn to run the test app I created. How can I get gunicorn to forget the oldtestapp and correctly run my new one?

Please let me know if any other information is needed. If it helps, I have committed the project to git without using a virtualenv. The Django application itself works without error (I have tested it elsewhere, I'm just trying to migrate it to heroku.)

I did a global search on all of the files in this heroku project to attempt to remove all occurrences of "oldtestapp" but there were none found.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may by chance run into the same issue, I did find a workaround:

I changed the Procfile to this:

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn
```

Essentially, the workaround here is to run gunicorn as a Django service instead of running Django from Gunicorn. Of course, gunicorn must be added to settings.py

I still don't understand the original problem though, and thus I think this is a workaround and not a solution- Thus, I'll leave this question open in case someone stumbles upon it with an answer.